# React Native developing on Windows for Android and ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, pod-install

i'm little bit confused about the installation of COCOAPODS and the installation gydes for react-native libaries.

If I developing on Windows for iOS and Android. Do I have installing the COCOAPODS?

And what about this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Do i have run the following command: npx pod-install ios

Or is this only if I developing on Mac?

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: For developing iOS on windows, you would have to install macOS on a VM in order to be able to run the simulator - in case if you don't have a physical device -, other wise @bjjeong answer is helpful.

Comment: What is if i only want to test my app on ios on a physical device? Do i have to install the pod to my project? I want develop the app for both platforms with the react-native source code. So If i don't install pod on windows and open the app on iOS will the app work then?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods is only needed when developing for iOS. You do not need to run `npx pod-install ios` when developing for Android. Android has its own methods for linking libraries.

While you can use Cocoapods on Windows (see [here](https://medium.com/@airtdave/using-cocoapods-on-windows-dec471735f51)), again, it's only for when you are developing for iOS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. to making sure. So if I want that my App also worked on iOS, than I have to install Cocoapods on Windows and run `npx pod-install ios` right?

Comment: @juri88 Yes that's the idea. However, I haven't developed any react native projects on Windows before so there may be other compatibility issues that you run into.

Comment: @bijeong okay thanks. do you have some ressources that would me help? and also how i install mac on windows and react-native and all the other stuff :D